# Inserting an element at any position in array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm relatively new to programming and some help would be appreciated. I'm receiving the error message: array index out of bounds.

```
static int[] insert1(int z, int arr[], int ins, int p)
{
    int i;


    int newarray[] = new int [z + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < z + 1 ; i++) {
        if (i < p - 1 )
            newarray[i] = arr[i];
        else if (i == p - 1)
            newarray[i] = ins;
        else
            newarray[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    return newarray;

}
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int ins = 20;
    int z = 5;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p = Integer.parseInt((scan.next()));

    arr = insert1(a, arr, ins, p);

    System.out.println("Insert Array:\t" + Arrays.toString(arr));

 }
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use an array? 
you can use arrayList if it is not a task.

Comment: Yes it is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it will make your life a lot easier to not have to put the length in as an input. Just using arr.length will give you the same result without having to worry about another variable.

You have a good start for an insertion. A more efficient and less complex way to do it would be with multiple for-loop.

```java
int newArray[] = new int[arr.length + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    newArray[i] = arr[i];
}
newArray[p] = ins;
for (int i = p + 1; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = arr[i - 1];
}
return newArray;
```

Let me know if this doesn't do what you're looking for and I can modify it.

P.S. If you are comfortable with changing more of your code you should look into using [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) instead. I'd be happy to add a version with a list to my answer.

Comment: Of course! No problem. If this works, you should mark it as "solution" so other people with the same issue can more easily find it